# Python and Modular Arithmetic

Tags: python, modular-arithmetic

Suppose `a` and `b` are odd integers. Then `a^2 + b^2` is either `2` or `10` modulo `16`. My question is the following: Is there a way of writing a script whose assumptions are `a%2 == 1` and `b%2 == 1` so that the output `(a^2 + b^2) % 16` gives the tuple `(2,10)`?
Edit: Here's my unsuccessful approach:

```
def test():
aList=[]
bList=[]
for a in range(0,16):
    for b in range(0,16):
        if a%2==1 and b%2==1:
            aList.append(a)
            bList.append(b)
            print  a^2+b^2%16
```

This of course will not return a tuple. My hope is to output the tuple (2,10).

Comment: you'll need to expand on the problem a bit. the `%` operator in python only returns a single value; not a tuple

Comment: You're looking for a script that produces all possible outputs from logical propositions? That's rather beyond what anything built-in on Python will do for you.

Comment: While this is a great question and lots of possibilities for us to explore, what have you explored so far? Can you show what you have done please? Or are you seeking answers from the community to get you started? We prefer that you show your work and seek help rather than us providing you answers.

Comment: `(a^2 + b^2) % 16` would always return an integer, never a tuple.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion that my question lead to. I'm aware that % returns a single value. My hope was for finding a command or package that would output the tuple (2,10) to the given question. With regards to Joe's question, I have edited my response to showcase my attempt at this.

Comment: Your edited question still doesn't show how a tuple is ever produced.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, you want to collect the distinct residues modulo 16 of `a**2 + b**2` (note the `^` operator is not what you want here) into a tuple. So instead of printing each residue out, you should add them to a set in order to collect the distinct values. The set can then be converted to a tuple, using `sorted` to get them in order:

```py
residues = set()
for a in range(0, 16):
    for b in range(0, 16):
        if a % 2 == 1 and b % 2 == 1:
            residues.add((a**2 + b**2) % 16)

residues = tuple(sorted(residues))
print(residues)
```

The result is `(2, 10)` as expected.

This code can be simplified somewhat: instead of generating all integers in the range and just keeping the odd ones, you can generate odd integers using a range starting from 1 with a step size of 2; and you can use a set comprehension for brevity.

```py
residues = {
    (a**2 + b**2) % 16
    for a in range(1, 16, 2)
    for b in range(1, 16, 2)
}

residues = tuple(sorted(residues))
print(residues)
```

Comment: @M.H.Tajaddini Your proposed edit is incorrect. Python ranges exclude their upper bound - `range(16)` goes up to 15, and `range(15)` would only go up to 14.